# MS Exchange 2007 Bounced mail

Tags: exchange-2007

Two things here...

1. I'm trying to figure out if Exchange 2007 have a log that shows all the bounced mail and why it was bounced. Does anyone know if this exists?
2. I'd also like to set up a transport rule that will forward any and all bounced mail to a certain account.

Any ideas on these?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691172%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) from Microsoft which will step you through troubleshooting message delivery failures on Exchange 2007. It should tell you all you need, and more.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  TLDR.